# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

This error shows several times while retrieving data from sqlite database. I closed database `onDestroy()` in activity and open the database in `onCreate()`. Please help me to resolve this type of issue.....

Comment: post some code where you are accessing db

Comment: there is some error in your code. But since you didn't share it, you will have to find it by yourself.

Comment: You should supply the logcat and code otherwise the only answer is that you are suffering from premature database closure.

Comment: I found out the solution, I have to close the cursors after getting data from database.

Answer (score 0):

Your Question is not Clear. 
But If you retrieve data in your existing database you can check file is exist or not using this,

```
File dbFile = myContext.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME);
return dbFile.exists();
```

And then your SQLIT data base using *SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase*

Answer (score 0):

DataBaseHelper baseHelper=new  DataBaseHelper(getActivity());
SQLiteDatabase  database=baseHelper.getReadableDatabase();

use this when you create connection from database.